# BroadcastReceiver.onReceive is called twice for user_present

Tags: android

I am having a strange(?) issue, I have implemented `BroadcastReceiver` for `USER_PRESENT`, it works fine on my Tablet but on my Galaxy S, it is triggered twice can some one shed some light here?

```
<receiver android:name="XYZBroadcastReceiver" >
   <intent-filter>                              
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT"/>                
  </intent-filter>              
</receiver>
```

I have a simple statement in `onReceive` method and its printed twice, in the logcat I see the following twice as well:

```
11-23 17:36:35.603: INFO/Launcher(2632): ACTION_USER_PRESENT
```

Comment: The problem is for my app too in Galaxy S.!! Post the solution anywhere if you've resolved it.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, in absence of any response in time, I had to move forward and I came up with work around.
Work around is that I check db and make sure that there is a time difference between 2 events at least >=1

This way whenever a quick call is made (which only happens on Galaxy s for now) no action is taken for the second quick call.

Answer (score 0):

May be you have installed the application twice in device (the broadcast receiver exist in tow different apps).

Please verify and uninstall all your test application. Then do the test and see if the log statement is printed in the log. Then install your application and see what happens.

Hope this could help you.

Comment: Are you sure the line does not appear if you uninstall your app and the intent that triggered your broadcast is broadcasted?

Comment: Ok Here is what I did (app is uninstalled already), 
Uninstall the app, ran lock phone then unlock, I see the following twice
11-23 21:37:21.349: INFO/Launcher(2608): ACTION_USER_PRESENT

I then turn off the phone, restart, once boot complete, I lock the phone and then unlock and saw the line
11-23 21:37:21.349: INFO/Launcher(2608): ACTION_USER_PRESENT
twice again. Now I am pretty sure that is the problem as this event is being triggered twice, hence my broadcast receiver is triggered twice. Just keep in mind that this does not happen on my tablet assus TF101

Answer (score 0):

I did this solution. I have created a simple semaphore. 
create a public class

```
public class Global {

public static  Boolean IS_RUNNING= false;
}
```

and in the BroadcastReceiver

```
public class ConnectivityReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


    if (Global.IS_RUNNING){
        //allready running!!! do nothing
        return;
    }
    Global.sendToLog("run the update");

    ... do stuff, in the end set Global.IS_RUNNING=false;

}
```

}

Comment: But you should find out the reason first. @Zeev G